# Empty unexplained (unwanted) space in grid container

Tags: css, flexbox, less, css-grid

I want that the content will fill the container without the empty space,
so that the container should be smaller.

[image: Empty unwanted space in grid container]

where this empty space is coming from? doesn't it should wrap the content by default?

the grid-css is seperate to 3 areas and in the right area I expect it would wrap around the content I don't know why it is so big.

Here is the HTML:

```
 <header class="header">


   <div class="left-pannel">
         <div class="main-menu"></div>
          <div class="logo"></div>
   </div>

   <div class="bread-crumbs">Operations > 360</div>

   <div class="right-pannel">
      <div class="search"></div>
       <div class="notifications"></div>
        <div class="tips"></div>
         <div class="history"></div>
          <div class="user-tips"></div>
   </div>

    and here is the less code:


.header {
    display:grid;
    height: 76px;
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    background-color: @blue-brand;
    align-items: center;
    grid-template-areas:"left-pannel bread-crumbs right-pannel";
    grid-gap:20px;
    color:@white;

    .left-pannel {
          grid-area: left-pannel;
          display: grid;
          grid-gap: 20px;
          grid-template-columns: minmax(40px, auto) 1fr;
          align-items: center;

                .main-menu {
                    height: 40px;
                    width: 40px;
                    margin-left: 24px;;
                    grid-column: 1 / 2;
                    background-image:url('../../assets/Images/Hamburger.svg');
                    background-position:50%;
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    }

                .logo {
                  height: 50px;
                  grid-column:2 / 3;
                  background-image: url('../../assets/Images/Logo.svg');
                  background-position: 0 50%;
                  background-repeat: no-repeat;
                  }

          }

        .bread-crumbs {
          grid-area: bread-crumbs;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: left;
          height: 50px;
          align-content: center;
          }

 .right-pannel {
                display: grid;
                grid-area: right-pannel;
                grid-auto-columns: minmax(252px, 252px) 40px 40px 40px 40px;
                grid-gap: 20px;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: end;
                margin-right: 32px;
                border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;

                 .search{
                  grid-column:1 / 2;
                  background-color: @blue-dark;
                  height:40px;
                                    }
  
                 .notifications{
                   grid-column:2 / 3;
                   height: 40px;
                   width: 40px;
                   background-image: url('../../assets/Images/Notifications.svg');
                                      }
       
                 .tips{
                   grid-column:3 / 4;
                   height: 40px;
                   width: 40px;
                   background-image: url('../../assets/Images/Tips.svg');
                                   }

                 .history{
                   grid-column:4 / 5;
                   height: 40px;
                   width: 40px;
                   background-image: url('../../assets/Images/History.svg');
                                 }

                  .user-tips{
                    grid-column:5 / 6;
                    height: 40px;
                    width: 40px;
                    background-image: url('../../assets/Images/User.svg');
                                    }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect because the length of the container is wider than the sum of the columns.

In other words:

```
252 + 40 + 40 + 40 + 40 + gaps < 100%
```

Try this instead:

```
grid-template-columns: 252px repeat(4, minmax(40px, 1fr))
```

This will make the columns take up the remain space.

Comment: I have tried still got the space there @Michael Benjamin

Comment: So please post all relevant code so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have @ Michael Benjamin

Comment: That's enough code to reproduce the problem? (I don't see any HTML.)

Comment: Updated  @Michael Benjamin

Comment: This is what your code renders: https://jsfiddle.net/azgy3rp7/

Comment: There's no gap in your demo. The problem you describe is not present.